# How to implement facets and item search using Elastic Search and Solr search engine

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, database-design, solr, architecture

I am working on a web app something like a digital library or archiving system, and before writing a code. I am thinking about the architecture design of this web application.

This system  will have multiple tables like `audio` `video` `book` `software` and much more

all table will have the common field called `title` and `id`, which I am thinking to index in `solr` or `elastic search` engine.

Let's say When I query a keyword `story` from my fronted using a simple search Form Via `REST/AJAX` to the search engine like `solr` or `elastic search`.

How do I access all the data from the `postgresql` table and total count info that matches the search query in search engine.

The overall architecture I am thinking is shown below.
[image]

Technology stack I am thinking is 
Database `PostgreSQL`
SearchEngine: `Don't know asking for recommendation`
BackEnd REST: `Django rest framework or express js`
Fronted: `Reactjs`

So, Summary: How do a multiple table search on PostgreSQL database using `solr` or `elastic search` so that I can have a complete result of the item_data match in each table as well as the item_details.

Comment: This is so simple that either elastic or solr or almost any other document search engine that supports facets should solve your problem.